# Setting background when content is floating

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains 2 columns. The left column is of a dynamic height, but the right column is always of a fixed height. TO do this I float both the column divs inside the container div. BUT, I want to set the background of the container div, and this doesn't do anything because there is no content - I only see the background color if I add a height to the container div, which I don't want to do.

How do I fix this?

```
<div id="container" style="background-color:pink" >
    <div class="col1" style="float:left;>...</div>
    <div class="col2" style="float:left; height:200px;>...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to [`clear`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/clear) the `float`s via [one way](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) or [another](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/). Also see [this post](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/)

Comment: @andyb i only though there was `"one direction"` to do that

Comment: @DiederikEEn Sorry, but I don't understand your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the float. There are three ways to doing this.

### Traditional

Just clear the float by adding an empty element to clear it.

```
<div style="background-color:pink">
  <div style="float:left;">...</div>
  <div style="float:left; height:200px;">...</div>
  <div style="clear:left"></div>
</div>
```

**You need add extra markup** which it isn't so nice at all.

### Overflow

A bit modern technique is to add an overflow. Could have a value of `auto` or `hidden`.

```
<div style="background-color:pink; overflow:auto;">
  <div style="float:left;">...</div>
  <div style="float:left; height:200px;">...</div>
</div>
```

This solution has some **some disadvantages** (see below).

### Micro-clearfix

Sometimes we can't use the overflow technique because we need to put something out of the element with an offset or whatever. Then we could use [Nicolas Gallagher's micro-clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/).

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}

/**
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */
.cf {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```

With this, just by adding the class `.cf` to the container element will work fine and hasn't the disadvantages from the overflow method and also you don't need to add any other extra markup. This is a nice solution and you could use it where you need it just by adding the class.

I recommend this last method. It's very clean and elegant.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because all of the child elements are floats. Add `overflow: hidden;` to the container div to make it wrap around the content. Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4pCsF/). If you want the div width wrapped around the content as well add `display: table;` to the container div.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're suffering from the famous collapsing container problem. Effectively, when you float the content of a container element the element will collapse down to the height of the largest unfloated element contained therein. If all of the contained elements and content of the container are floated the containing element will collapse down to nothing.

There are two options to fix this, firstly you can add some extra markup like this...

```
<div id="container" style="background-color:pink" >
    <div class="col1" style="float:left;>...</div>
    <div class="col2" style="float:left; height:200px;>...</div>
    <!-- This <br /> is an unfloated element that clears the floated elements above -->
    <!-- thus acting as an HTML 'wedge' -->
    <br style="clear:both;" /> 
</div>
```

... but this adds extra markup

Alternatively you can do it using CSS like this (assuming your original code)

```
#container:after   {content: ".";display: block;height: 0;clear: both;visibility: hidden;}
#container         {display: inline-block;}
* html #container  {height: 1%;}
#container         {display: block;}
```

which prevents you from having to add any extra HTML at all.

A happy compromise is to replace `#container` with `.cf` (or similar - I use cf for 'clearfix') and apply the .cf class to anything that suffers from this problem.

For further explanation of this technique try googling clearfix. This method above may have been outdated by now - I just dug this out of my code library  :)